# Change the facing with a turn_left method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to create a method turn_left who changes the facing, facing always start in :south (Im implementing a robot who moves into a board) so if i call method turn_left should change the facing to East and then to North and to West and then return to south. Im thinking in something like this:

```
    {
     0: S
     1: E
     2: N
     3: W
    }
```

this is my code

```
# Models the Robor behavior for the game
class Robot

 def initialize(attr = {})
 # @position = attr[:position]
 # @move = attr[:move]
   @facing = :south
 # @turn_left =
 # @turn_right =
 # @errors =
 end

 def position
 end

 def move
 end

 def facing
  @facing
 end

 def turn_left

 end

 def turn_right
 end

 def errors
 end
end
```

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: oh Im kinda new here I thought that I should select one if works but yea you are right! :)

Comment: Got it! was because my whole platform is building in Rails but yea, this part is just Ruby.

Comment: This is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
class Robot
  FACINGS = [:south, :east, :north, :west]

  def initialize(attr = {})
    @facing_index = 0 # south
  end

  def facing
    FACINGS[@facing_index]
  end

  def turn_left
    @facing_index += 1
    @facing_index %= 4
  end

  def turn_right
    @facing_index -= 1
    @facing_index %= 4
  end
end
```

The `%= 4` (or, if you really want to generalise this further, `%= FACINGS.length`) performs modulo arithmetic to "wrap" the current index back into the range 0-3.

Therefore by incrementing/decrementing this number, you can toggle between the four directions.

---

I don't know how you intent to implement `position`, `move` and `errors`, but I presume that's beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Just wanted to answer it this way, and refreshed to see answers xD

Comment: Yea. Its is because I need to change position according to facing and assigns no errors if it moves succesfully.

Answer (score 4):

You could store the directions in an array:

```
def initialize
  @dirs = [:S, :W, :N, :E]
end
```

With the [`first`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-first) entry being the facing direction:

```
def facing
  @dirs.first
end
```

When the robot turns left, you [`rotate!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-rotate-21) the array counter clockwise:

```
def turn_left
  @dirs.rotate! -1
end
```

Or clockwise when turning right: (the `1` could be omitted here)

```
def turn_right
  @dirs.rotate! 1
end
```

Comment: As you know, and probably considered, an alternative is `@right = [:N, :E, :S, :W].cycle; def turn_right; @facing = @right.next; end; def turn_left; 3.times { turn_right }; end; attr_reader :facing`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland if only there were "two-way" enumerators with both, `next` and `prev`.

Comment: Yes, that would be handy.

Answer (score 4):

```
left = {:n=>:w, :w=>:s, :s=>:e, :e=>:n}
right = left.invert
  #=> {:w=>:n, :s=>:w, :e=>:s, :n=>:e}

pos = :s

pos = left[pos]
  #=> :e
pos = right[pos]
  #=> :w
```

Comment: For this use case, I like the "old" `:n=>:w` syntax much more ;-)

Comment: Your wish is my command, @Stefan. I agree. (Readers: I formerly had `n: :w`, etc.)

Comment: A downside to this approach is that it's quite limited to one action ("turn left") and its inverse ("turn right"). Implementing something else, like "turn around" or turn by a different amount (if there were more than 4 directions) breaks the otherwise quite elegant design pattern.

Comment: I mean, of course you can still achieve it - e.g. `left[left[pos]]` to turn around. It just loses its elegance.

Comment: @Tom, that's true, but we could also define `turn_around = { :n=>:s, :s=>:n, :e=>:w, :w=>:e }`.

Comment: Yes, you could - but that's not very DRY. And the problem would become more apparent, as i said, if there were more than 4 directions. (NW, SW, SE, NE?)

Answer (score 2):

I would go with degrees instead of an enumeration. That way you can manipulate the facing by adding/subtracting *n* degrees from the current facing.

```
class Robot
  attr_accessor :facing

  def initialize(**attrs)
    self.facing = attrs[:facing] || 180 # south
  end

  def rotate!(degrees)
    self.facing = (self.facing + degrees) % 360
  end

  def rotate_left!
    rotate!(-90)
  end

  def rotate_right!
    rotate!(90)
  end
end
```

You can then use a relatively simple method to convert degrees to cardinal (compass points):

```
class Robot
  COMPASS_POINTS = %w[N E S W]

  # ...

  def compass_point
    seg_size = 360 / COMPASS_POINTS.size
    COMPASS_POINTS[((facing + (seg_size / 2)) % 360) / seg_size]
  end
end
```

This one is taken from the [geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/22051b907e3b6f18d5c9c82011aa080b890cd03d/lib/geocoder/calculations.rb).

This might seem a bit more complicated but lets you store executed commands as `rotate: 90` or `rotate: -90` if you want to keep track of it. It also lets you rotate the robot a full (stepless) 360 degrees if wanted.

Comment: `rotate!` can just be `self.facing = (self.facing + degrees) % 360`

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky, I knew there had to be a smarter way using modulus.