# Change position according to facing in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to implement a move method that change position according to facing, position is a [x,y] and I thinking that if move to south is y+1, to north y-1, to east x-1 and to west x+1. this movements are into a matrix. 
This is my code. Thank you so much for your help!

```
# Models the Robot behavior for the game
class Robot
 FACINGS = [:south, :east, :north, :west]

 def initialize(attr = {})
  @position = attr[:position] || [1, 1]
  # @move = attr[:move]
  @facing_index = facing_index(attr[:facing]) || 0 # south
  @facing = facing
  # @errors =
 end

 def position
  @position
 end

 def move

 end

 def facing
  @facing = FACINGS[@facing_index]
 end

 def errors
 end

 private

 def facing_index(facing)
  facing if facing.is_a? Integer
  FACINGS.index(facing&.to_sym)
 end
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the facing with a turn\_left method in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53285855/change-the-facing-with-a-turn-left-method-in-ruby)

Comment: What's the difference from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53285855/change-the-facing-with-a-turn-left-method-in-ruby?

Comment: This is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: It looks like SO has been tasked with writing a robot game from scratch?

Comment: Thank u guys!! Im implementing a game into a platform to teach kids to code and I had some issues with that but I already finished! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DIRECTION_NUMBER = { :north=>0, :east=>1, :south=>2, :west=>3 }

@left = { :north=>:west, :west=>:south, :south=>:east, :east=>:north }
@right = @left.invert
  #=> {:west=>:north, :south=>:west, :east=>:south, :north=>:east}

def turn_left
  @facing = @left[@facing]
end

def turn_right
  @facing = @right[@facing]
end

def move(direction)
  x, y = @location
  @location =
  case direction
  when :north
    [x,y+1]
  when :east
    [x+1,y]
  when :south
    [x,y-1]
  else
    [x-1,y]
  end
  update_facing(direction)
end
```

```
private

def update_facing(direction)
  change = (DIRECTION_NUMBER[direction] - DIRECTION_NUMBER[@facing]) % 4
  case change
  when 1
    turn_right
  when 2
    turn_right; turn_right
  when 3
    turn_left
  end
end
```

```
@location = [3, 3]    
@facing = :east

move(:south)
@location   #=> [3, 2]
@facing     #=> :south

move(:north)
@location   #=> [3, 3]
@facing     #=> :north

move(:west)
@location   #=> [2, 3]
@facing     #=> :west

move(:east)
@location   #=> [3, 3]
@facing     #=> :east
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `MOVES` which says how to move based on how you're facing.

```
MOVES = {
  north: [0, 1],
  south: [0, -1],
  east:  [1, 0],
  west:  [-1,0]
}

def move
  move = MOVES.fetch(@facing)
  @position[0] += move[0]
  @position[1] += move[1]
end
```

[`MOVES.fetch(@facing)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) is used instead of `MOVES[@facing]` so an error will be raised if there is no move for that facing.

You could also do this with a `case` statement, but this keeps `move` simple and data driven. You can add more directions like `northeast: [1,1]`. And if you make this an instance variable, you can customize how individual robots move.

```
# Define `moves` and `moves=` to get and set `@moves`
attr_accessor :moves

def initialize(attr = {})
  ...
  # Initialize `moves` with either Robot.new(moves: {...})
  # or the default MOVES
  @moves ||= attr[:moves] || MOVES
  ...
end

def move
  move = moves.fetch(@facing)
  @position[0] += move[0]
  @position[1] += move[1]
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Schwern!!

Answer (score 1):

FACINGS enum example.

```
module FACINGS
  NORTH = [0, 1]
  SOURTH = [0, -1]
  EAST =  [1, 0]
  WEST =  [-1,0]
end

class Robot
  attr_reader :position

  def initialize(attr = {})
    @position = attr[:position] || [1, 1]
  end

  def move(facings)
    @position[0] += facings[0]
    @position[1] += facings[1]
  end
end

r = Robot.new
r.move(FACINGS::NORTH)
r.move(FACINGS::SOURTH)
r.move(FACINGS::WEST)
r.move(FACINGS::EAST)
```